# Pandas: str extract text every thing except the last part of the string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe with a column known as "msg".

In the "msg" column, all rows goes somesthing like below. User xxxx is of length 6 or 7 characters. xx.xx.xx.xx and yy.yy.yy.yy are ip addresses thus every octet could be 1 digit or 3 digits.

```
User xxxxxx is attempting to restart primary host xxx.xx.xxx.xx (id=1) for managed host yyy.yy.yyy.yy (id=4) at Dec 30, 2019, 6:08:87 PM
```

I need a rule to extract everything in each cell before "at Dec 30, 2019, 6:08:87 Pm"? i.e I want to drop all characters after "at \w\w\w \d\d, \d\d\d\d, \d:\d\d:\d\d ....."

My current code is as below but I not sure how to fill in the pat.

```
Test = df['msg'].str.extract(pat='...')
```

Respond to comments below:
Matthew: yes.  The format after the 2nd (id=xx) are the same. 
Jon: either way is OK.

Comment: do all the msg columns end in the format `at Dec 30, 2019, 6:08:87 PM`

Comment: Do you need a regex or can you just take everything before the last " at" that appears?

Comment: Presumably, you are not just interested in strings that contain the literal `at Dec 30, 2019, 6:08:87 PM`. You need to state the *rule* for determining where the string you wish to extract ends. Please do that by editing your question, and in your edit answer the questions raised in the previous two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead regex here:

```
Test = df['msg'].str.extract(pat='^.*(?=\s+at [A-Za-z]{3} \d{2}, \d{4}, [\d:]+ (?:AM|PM)$)')
```

Here is a regex demo showing that the above pattern is working:

### Demo

Comment: Do you need `^`? Having `$` may be a nuisance if, for example, there's an extra space at the end, given the pattern of strings seems to be consistent.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't know if `str.extract` defaults to starting from the start of the input; I am pretty sure that `^` and `$` are not included by default.  The `$` in the lookahead is ensure that this is the _last_ such timestamp.  Maybe you are right, and this is overkill.

Comment: I'd be surprise if `.*` didn't start at the beginning, but no harm, no foul with `^`.

Comment: Actually, I'd be surprised if `.*` _did_ start at the beginning without specifying `^`.  Otherwise, `str.extract` could not be used to find content in the middle of the text.

Comment: was working on similar, putting explanation to regular users in my org. Posted. Let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
string='I ate an apple (id=1) and an orange (id=4) at Dec 30, 2019, 6:08:87 PM'
string = string[:string.rfind('at')]
```

Here, I guess the word 'at' should be before the date. Hence what I did is found the last_occurence of 'at' using rfind() and sliced the string

Comment: Hi, This works but my string is inside a dataframe[eachRow]['Remarks'][index]. I tihink I can check row by row but there another way to extract entire column all at once like using df.str.extract()? Because I have multiple 'eachRow' which represents a lot of users and each users have multiple rows to be extreacted too.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
df.msg.str.extractall('(?<=\s)([a-z]*\s[A-Z0-9]\S*\s[0-9,].+)')
```

Explanation

`(?<=\s)` Any expression after space followed by lower case aphas and space [`a-z]*\s` and an upper case alphanumeric`[A-Z0-9]`
and the alphanumeric may match non-whitespace `\S`
and may match a string white space greedily to the left zero or multiple times `*\s` and may also have strings with digits between  0-9 and comma`[0-9,]` and if this pattern exists match those characters except terminators greedily to the the left zero or multiple times`.+`

Comment: Hi, I tested in https://regexr.com/ but it seems to capture only text from "at Dec" onwards till the end.

Comment: You are right, that's what I wrote it to do.Sorry, misread your question. Ignore it